# Can a recursive call crash the Jupyter notebook kernel

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

i'm new here. I hope this question could be of value to others too.

Obviously a recursive call can overflow the stack and that will "crash" any program/script.

However, I was wondering, in particular, whether overflowing the stack with a recursive call could generate the following message in Jupyter Notebook (python 3.x):

> Kernel Restarting
>
> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Edit: The above message, refers to the python Kernel that the Jupyter Notebook is running.

I am aware that something else might be causing the crash, but in order to help me narrow my options (and confirm my very strong suspicion) I will like to make sure that this is indeed the message Jupyter Notebook would display in the case of a recursive stack overflow.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes but your question needs to be specific you are talking about Jupyter kernel. This is not the OS kernel.

Comment: You are correct. I will edit that to clarify. Thank you.